# Issue: JWPlayer always replay from 0 position when url update

Tags: javascript, video, jwplayer

I am new to jwplayer.

I have video URL
http://wpc.3DA92.deltacdn.net/803DA92/IDC/f_1/idc.m3u8?**signature1**.

signature1 is just string.

I am playing this video in jwplayer.

but I need to update signature every 2 minutes So, I have set interval to get new signature(http://wpc.3DA92.deltacdn.net/803DA92/IDC/f_1/idc.m3u8?**signature2**) and set it for jwplayer.

both video are same just signature change.

So, my issue is that video is replay when I have get updated signature and set for jwplayer by following code

```
jwplayer('watch-video').setup(fnGetJwpOpt(video));

function fnGetJwpOpt(video) {
                var jwOption = {
                    skin: {
                        background: '#000000',
                        inactive: '#ffffff',
                        active: '#ff0000'
                    },
                    captions: {
                        color: '#0000ff'
                    },
                    width: '100%',
                    repeat: false
                };

                var windowWidth = angular.element($window).width();

                if (windowWidth < 768) {
                    jwOption.aspectratio = '16:9';
                } else {
                    jwOption.height = 500;
                }

                jwOption.playlist = [{
                    sources: [{
                        file: video.url
                    }],
                    image: video.img,
                    title: video.title
                }];

                jwOption.abouttext = video.text;

                return jwOption;
            }
```

and after play video

```
jwplayer('watch-video').play();
```

So, when I am playing video and update signature every 2 minutes for jwplayer and video play every time video replay from starting.

I want to continue playing video on that position before update signature...
not replay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the current position that you want to resume, like so:

```
var currentPositionInVideo = jwplayer('playerId').getPosition();
```

Then when instantiating your player, you can place the following in the onReady callback function, like so:

```
    ...
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    events: {
      onReady: function() {
        jwplayer('playerId').seek(currentPositionInVideo );
      },
    ...
```

You must specify the seek position in seconds. Here is a pen which shows how the `.seek()` API function works.

http://codepen.io/simsketch/pen/gLNVYb

Edit: If you want to take it a step further, you can save the currentPositionVideo variable to localStorage so that it's there in case the user refreshes or something, like this.

```
localStorage.setItem("currentPosVid",currentPositionInVideo);
```

then retrieve like so

```
var currentPos = localStorage.getItem("currentPosVid")
```